# Change Youtube Data API PublishAt Date Format

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, androidx

I have an Android app, i use Youtube Data API V3 for loading a certain channels content. showing the Video, video title and video Publish Date, the current Video Publish Date is shown in this format 2015-01-21T11:20:27.751+00:00
I want to change it to yyyy-MM-dd format if possible, your help will be appreciated.
The code for the Date is below.

```
TextView textViewDate = holder.textViewDate;
textViewDate.setText(object.getPublishedAt());
```

the code **getPublishedAt()** is loaded from Youtube Data API.

Comment: What type does `getPublishedAt()` return?

Answer (score 3):

Since the method `getPublishedAt()` seems to return an instance of `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime`, which doesn't have a date-only representation, you might have to convert it.

I would convert it using `getValue()` of the `DateTime` using `java.time` like this:

```
long epochMillis = object.getPublishedAt().getValue();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis),
                                                      ZoneId.systemDefault());
String date = zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
textViewDate.setText(date);
```

You are coding for Android, so the availability of `java.time` (since Java 8) depends on the API levels your app is supporting. You can use the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) in order to support lower levels than 26.